# How to create the greek orthodox easter calendar in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am a newbie in SQL and i really need your help for my project. So, i had to create a master calendar table (which i have already created with the name "DimDate") but the problem is that i can't define right the function for the Easter Holidays in Greece.

I'm trying to create a function which will return the Easter Holidays (e.g Easter Sunday, Easter Monday, Good Friday) using the Meeus's Julian algorithm and not the Gregorian.

The function i have already tried, concerns the Gregorian calendar and as a result i get wrong dates for most of Easter Sundays. For example, for the year 2015, i see from the result of my query that the Easter Sunday was on 05/04/2015 (dd/MM/yyy) BUT the truth is that on 2015 the real date of Easter Sunday in Greece was 12/04/2015. And this is because i used the Gregorian algorithm as you can see below in the code i used.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEasterHolidays(@year INT) 
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN 

    (

      WITH x AS 

      (

        SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, RTRIM(@year) + '0' + RTRIM([Month]) 
            + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM([Day]),2))
          FROM (SELECT [Month], [Day] = DaysToSunday + 28 - (31 * ([Month] / 4))
          FROM (SELECT [Month] = 3 + (DaysToSunday + 40) / 44, DaysToSunday
          FROM (SELECT DaysToSunday = paschal - ((@year + @year / 4 + paschal - 13) % 7)
          FROM (SELECT paschal = epact - (epact / 28)
          FROM (SELECT epact = (24 + 19 * (@year % 19)) % 30) 
            AS epact) AS paschal) AS dts) AS m) AS d
      )

      SELECT [Date], HolidayName = 'Easter Sunday' FROM x
        UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-2,[Date]), 'Good Friday'   FROM x
        UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1,[Date]), 'Easter Monday' FROM x

    );
```

--- Now 'updating' my "DimDate" calendar table---

```
;WITH x AS 
    (

      SELECT d.[Date], d.IsHolidayEU, d.HolidayEU, h.HolidayName
        FROM dbo.DimDate AS d
        CROSS APPLY dbo.GetEasterHolidays(d.[Year]) AS h
        WHERE d.[Date] = h.[Date]

    )

UPDATE x SET IsHolidayEU = 1, HolidayEU = HolidayName;
```

I have searched the internet extensively and i found what i wanted but in HANA, not sql. I am confused since i tried to convert the HANA Code i found into sql but didn't manage it. 
Also, here is the link from the HANA code i found, it contains 2 pictures.
I think i need to convert the second (image) code into sql server statements. 
https://blogs.sap.com/2015/04/08/happy-easter-folks-easter-date-calculation/

Please help me if you can...and thank you in advance. 
*Sorry for the looks of the code, i am new here, i couldn't find the way to make it better in order to be whole inside the "grey" area

Comment: Could you add some test cases? IE '2018' -> '01/01/2018' (or whenever would be correct)

Comment: Right now your question will only be useful to people who know how Easter holidays are calculated, or who are willing and able to follow your link.   When that link goes dead, this question will be useless to future readers.   You should put everything needed to understand the question in the question itself.

Comment: Tab Alleman, I am sorry for the way i posted the question, i am new, i ll try better next time..I believe i have to follow the Meeus's Julian algorithm in order to get the right dates for greek easter holidays through years (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus).

Comment: Cowthulhu, thank you for replying, i write some right examples: i.e the Easter Sunday for 2018 in Greece was on 18/04/2018..Actually, here is the link i found which exhibits all the Easter Sundays for example for all years..https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/greece/easter-sunday

Comment: Also, thanks for updating the appearance of the code i posted!

Comment: FYI, it's completely reasonable to manually update your calendar with holidays for the next 100 years if that makes it any easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is a great function that works great at least until 2100.
In order to not have performance issues create a temp table with the given dates like this:

```
WITH estdates as    
(SELECT c.fd EasterSunday
    , c.[Year] 
    , DATEADD(dd,-2,c.fd) EasterFriday
    , DATEADD(dd,1,c.fd) EasterMonday
FROM
(
    SELECT dbo.UDF_GetEaster_Orthodox( ur.YR)  fd,ur.YR [Year]
    FROM         
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N1.N) +1999 AS YR  
        FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS N1(N)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS N2(N)
      ) AS ur
  ) c
)
select * 
into #EasterHolidays
from 
(SELECT EasterFriday EasterHolidays FROM estdates d
UNION ALL
SELECT EasterMonday FROM estdates d ) a
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to get the right results with the following code.
The first function gives the Easter Sunday:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Easter_Orthodox22(@YEAR INT)
RETURNS DATE

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @EasterMonth INT,
     @EasterDay INT,
     @Easter NVARCHAR(10),
     @EYear VARCHAR(4),
     @EMonth VARCHAR(2),
     @EDay VARCHAR(2),
     @EasterDate DATE,
     @a INT,
     @b INT,
     @c INT,
     @d INT,
     @e INT;

SET @a = @YEAR%4;
SET @b = @YEAR%7;
SET @c = @YEAR%19;
SET @d = (19 * @c + 15)%30;
SET @e = (2 * @a + 4 * @b - @d +34)%7;

SET @EasterDay = (((@d + @e + 114)%31)+1);
SET @EasterMonth = CAST(((@d + @e + 114)/31) AS INT);
SET @EYear = CAST( @YEAR AS VARCHAR(4));
SET @EMonth = CAST( @EasterMonth AS VARCHAR(2));
SET @EDay = CAST( @EasterDay AS VARCHAR(2));

SET @Easter = CONCAT( CONCAT( @EYear, RIGHT( CONCAT('0', @EMonth),2)), RIGHT ( CONCAT('0', @EDay),2));
SET @EasterDate = CAST( @Easter AS DATE);
SET @EasterDate = DATEADD( day, 13, @EasterDate);
RETURN @EasterDate;
END
GO
```

Then, i created two more functions in order to find the Easter Monday and Great Friday:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEasterMonday2 (@YEAR INT) 
RETURNS DATE
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN (SELECT convert(date,convert(datetime,dbo.Easter_Orthodox2(@YEAR)) + 1)) 
END 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetGoodFriday2 (@YEAR INT) 
RETURNS DATE
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN (SELECT convert(date,convert(datetime,dbo.Easter_Orthodox2(@YEAR)) - 2)) 
END 
GO
```

But, now i am facing a different problem! A performance one, when i try to update my master calendar. I do the following in order to update the calendar:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[DimDate]
    SET IsHolidayEU = 1,
    HolidayEU = 'Easter Sunday'
WHERE [DATE] = dbo.Easter_Orthodox22(@CurrentYear)

UPDATE [dbo].[DimDate]
    SET IsHolidayEU = 1,
    HolidayEU = 'Good Friday'
WHERE [DATE] = dbo.GetGoodFriday2(@CurrentYear)

UPDATE [dbo].[DimDate]
    SET IsHolidayEU = 1,
    HolidayEU = 'Easter Monday'
WHERE [DATE] =  dbo.GetEasterMonday2(@CurrentYear)
```

These Update expression are written inside a while loop inside my calendar code..I think that i should have used the "SCHEMABINDING" and/or "CROSS APPLY" with "with-query" that is exhibited in the primary code but don't know how to change my code into that in order to improve the performance..Any help appreciated guys!