Calculate eastern easter date in SQL
I need help calculating the Eastern / Orthodox Easter. I tried searching here and all I found was the Western / Catholic Easter, not the Eastern / Orthodox Easter. I found a python snippet, and I want to convert it to T-SQL, but it gives me wrong results.
The python snippet:
y=2025
d=(y%19*19+15)%30
e=(y%4*2+y%7*4-d+34)%7+d+127
m=e/31
a=e%31+1+(m>4)
if a>30:a,m=1,5
print (a,'/',m,'/',y)

The SQL is trying to convert it to:
DECLARE @param_YEAR_NUMBER SMALLINT = 2025;

DECLARE @local_YEAR_IN_LUNAR_CYCLE TINYINT = @param_YEAR_NUMBER % 19;

DECLARE @local_YEAR_PERIOD_IN_LUNAR_CYCLE TINYINT = @local_YEAR_IN_LUNAR_CYCLE * 19;

DECLARE @local_FIX_1 TINYINT = (@local_YEAR_PERIOD_IN_LUNAR_CYCLE + 15) % 30;

DECLARE @local_FIX_2 TINYINT = ((((@param_YEAR_NUMBER % 4) *2) + ((@param_YEAR_NUMBER % 7) * 4) - @local_FIX_1 + 34) % 7) + @local_FIX_1 + 127;

DECLARE @local_EASTERN_EASTER_MONTH TINYINT = @local_FIX_2 / 31;}

DECLARE @local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY TINYINT = (@local_FIX_1 % 31) + 1;

IF (@local_EASTERN_EASTER_MONTH > 4)
BEGIN
    SET @local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY = @local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY + 1;
END;
    
IF (@local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY > 30)
BEGIN
    SET @local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY = 1;

    SET @local_EASTERN_EASTER_MONTH = 5;
END;

With my SQL code I get April 15, instead of April 20 (Easter date for 2025). What's wrong with my code? I don't know much Python, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

In most years, Orthodox Easter follows Western Easter by one or more weeks. To determine the Orthodox Easter Sunday date, it is first necessary to find the Julian Easter Sunday date, then to add the number of days which have been "skipped" in the Gregorian calendar.

See Calculate the Date of Easter Sunday  at https://www.assa.org.au/edm#OrthCalculator

Have you tried executing both codes line by line and comparing the results to see when they diverge?

That python snippet returns 21 / 4.612903225806452 / 2025 anyway so I'm not sure I'd rely on that as my start point...

@AlanSchofield I'm guessing it was written in python 2, where / is integer division.

If I'm not mistaken, DECLARE @local_EASTERN_EASTER_DAY TINYINT = (@local_FIX_1 % 31) + 1; should feature FIX_2 and not FIX_1 (which you'd have found with a step by step comparison)

Catholic Easter is Sun, Apr 20, 2025.  To find Orthodox Easter: use table A 2025/19=106.578 gives Paschal Full Moon = A4. From tables B,C, & D we get 2+6+3=11. Using table E we get Days to add for next Sunday =3. So Paschal Full Moon A4+3=A7.  From table F we get Skipped Days to Add =13.  A7+13=A20.

Why bother calculating this in t-sql. Just get the range you want and put the values in a table.

TINYINT is not large enough for all possible results for local_YEAR_PERIOD_IN_LUNAR_CYCLE. You probably still need smallint here.

I suggest you use this formula adapted from Turanos question How to create the greek orthodox easter calendar in sql server?
DECLARE @year SMALLINT = 2025;
    
SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, RTRIM(@year) + '0' + RTRIM([Month]) 
                + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM([Day]),2)) as OrthodoxEaster
FROM (SELECT [Month], [Day] = DaysToSunday + 28 - (31 * ([Month] / 4))
FROM (SELECT [Month] = 3 + (DaysToSunday + 40) / 44, DaysToSunday
FROM (SELECT DaysToSunday = paschal - ((@year + @year / 4 + paschal - 13) % 7)
FROM (SELECT paschal = epact - (epact / 28)
FROM (SELECT epact = (24 + 19 * (@year % 19)) % 30) 
                AS epact) AS paschal) AS dts) AS m) AS d

Another solution was found and adapted from
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/calculating-easter-in-sql
New Scientist (30 March 1961) - Modification of the Anonymous Gregorian algorithm
/*    
a       y % 19                       year's position in 19-year lunar phase cycle
b, c    y / 100, y % 100             corrections for century years
d, e    b / 4, b % 4                 leap-year exceptions in century years
g       8 * b + 13 / 25              century-year auxiliary corrections to the new-moon and full-moon dates
h       (19*a + b - d - g + 15) % 30 number of days between 21 March and the coincident or next following full moon
i, k    c / 4, c % 4                 position of the year in the ordinary leap-year cycle
l       (32 + 2*e + 2*i - h - k) % 7 number between 0 and 6 which is one less than the number of days before the next Sunday which is definitely after the full moon
m       (a + 11*h + 19*l) / 433          correction for transfer of full moon from a Sunday to a Saturday m = 1 for the required correction else 0
n       (h + l - 7*m + 90) / 25          the month on the Gregorian Calendar h + l - 7*m = number of days between 21 March and Easter
p       (h + l - 7*m + 33*n + 19) % 32)  the day of the month on the Gregorian calendar
*/

DECLARE @y SMALLINT = 2025;
            
Select * --e9.EasterDay
From (Values (@y % 19, @y / 100, @y % 100))                       As e1(a, b, c)
Cross Apply (Values (b / 4, b % 4))                               As e2(d, e)
Cross Apply (Values ((8*b + 13) / 25))                            As e3(g)
Cross Apply (Values ((19*a + b - d - g + 15) % 30, c / 4, c % 4)) As e4(h, i, k) 
Cross Apply (Values ((32 + 2*e + 2*i - h - k) % 7))               As e5(l)
Cross Apply (Values ((a + 11*h + 19*l) / 433))                    As e6(m)
Cross Apply (Values ((h + l - 7*m + 90) / 25))                    As e7(n)
Cross Apply (Values ((h + l - 7*m + 33*n + 19) % 32))             As e8(p)
Cross Apply (Values (datefromparts(@y, n, p)))                    As e9(EasterDay)

fiddle

I know it was not your code, but using a series of CROSS APPLYs to calculate intermediate results can eliminate the deeply nested selects and (subjectively) make the code more readable. Also, DATEFROMPARTS() can be used for the final date conversion. See this db<>fiddle.

Yes I saw that style via this link https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/calculating-easter-in-sql

Boths formulas are incorrect. In 2024, Orthodox Easter was on 5 May, but the queries return 31 March.

You should use the code in Turanos answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627251/1187211 (not from his question, where he clearly states "i get wrong dates for most of Easter Sundays").

Here is a better formula, based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_of_Easter#Gauss's_Easter_algorithm:
DECLARE @year SMALLINT = 2024;

SELECT *, DATEADD(DAY,dif,DATEFROMPARTS(y,m,dy)) AS OrthodoxEasterDate
FROM (SELECT @year AS y) x0
CROSS APPLY (SELECT a=y%4, b=y%7, c=y%19) x1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT d=(19*c+15)%30) x2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT e=(2*a+4*b-d+34)%7) x3
CROSS APPLY (SELECT f=d+e+114) x4
CROSS APPLY (SELECT m=FLOOR(f/31)) x5
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dy=f%31+1) x6
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN y BETWEEN 1900 AND 2099 THEN 13 END AS dif) x7 

